# Object.defineProperties() - assigning new value to property after defining it

Tags: javascript, oop

In the 1st code given below where the object is `book`, in the beginning `book.year` is set to `2013`. When i assigned `book.year = 2015` and again tried to retrieve its value by executing `book.year` i still get `2013` instead of `2015`. Where i am doing wrong??

The code is given below:

```
var book = {};
Object.defineProperties(book, {
    _yearOrigin: {
        value: 2013
    },
    edition: {
        value: "1st"
    },
    year: {
        get: function(){return this._yearOrigin},

        set: function(newValue){
            //assigning this._yearOrigin
            this._yearOrigin = newValue; 

            //carrying the operation for evaluating the `subscript` to add in this.edition
            //diff = difference in year
            var diff = String(newValue - 2013); 
            var diffLast2ndChar = diff.charAt(diff.length - 2);
            var diffLastChar = diff.charAt(diff.length - 1);
            var subscript = "";

            if (diff.length > 1 && diffLast2ndChar == "1") {
                subscript = "th"; 
            } else {
                subscript = diffLastChar == "1"
                                ? "st"
                                : diffLastChar == "2"
                                    ? "nd"
                                    : diffLastChar == "3"
                                        ? "rd"
                                        : "th" ;
            }
            //--end of subscript evaluation

            //assigment operation of this.edition
            var rawEdition = Number(this.edition.charAt(0)) + Number(diff);
            this.edition = String(rawEdition) + subscript;
        }
    }
});

>>> book.year = 2015
>>>book.year //output is 2013 , but expected output is 2015
```

Whereas, in contrast, in another equivalent piece of code given below when tried to retrieve the value of `book2.year`, after assigning `book2.year = 2013`, gives the output `2013` as expected

```
var book2 = {
    _year: 2004,
    edition: 1
};
Object.defineProperty(book2, "year", {
    get: function(){
        return this._year;
    },
    set: function(newValue){
        if (newValue > 2004) {
            this._year = newValue;
            this.edition += newValue - 2004;
        }
    }
});

book2.year = 2005;
console.log(book2.year); //2005 (Now this time the output is expected unlike in the previous code shown above)
```

Comment: In the first part you are setting the value of your `_yearOrigin` to `2013` as a constant value. As you only give the [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) parameter, it is seen as an immutable value. In the second version, you define a property on an object, with a default value of `2004`. There is a big difference there

Comment: Properties created by `defineProperties()` with a `value`, such as `_yearOrigin`, default to being non-[`writable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) (immutable).

Comment: @Icepickle @Jonathan what shall i do then?? Do i need to specify `writable: true` or something else??

Comment: @JonathanLonowski @Icepickle Adding `writtable: true` did the job. I was missing a silly thing

Comment: That depends, you now lost the ability to control the value (i guess that's why you wrote an extra setter for this value)

Comment: @Icepickle I lost the ability to control the value?? i guess you are referring to the fact that `Enumerable`,  `configurable` and other associated property default to `false`. Again if i am being oblivious of something, please do mention

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked to the fact that "when using `Object.Property/Object.properties` to define a property of an object, default `writable` to `false`, i.e, the defined value can't be change(non writable)" which was mentioned by guys in the comment section.

when i added `writable = true` as shown below, then the problem got solved and the expected result popped out

```
_yearOrigin: {
    value: 2013,
    writable: true
},
```

Comment: don't forget that this now also means it can be set from any part of your code, while in your opening question, you used it rather like a private property. This means that throughout your code, you can no longer be sure that _yearOrigin is really the origin, or has been set without having the checks in your separate setter in place